# Создание конвертера файлов формата MDL(Rathional Rose)

Tags: case

Мне нужно создать конвертер файлов формата MDL (UML диаграммы Rathional Rose) в файл определенной структуры. В моем случае это EKB (описание структуры представлю ниже). Пытался найти в интернете структуру MDL файлов, однако ничего толкового не нашел. Собственно у меня два вопроса. Как выглядит структура MDL файла и с чего начать разработку конвертера, ибо я слабо понимаю как одну структуру преобразовать в другую.

Структура EKB:

```
<Structure>
   <KnowledgeBase>
       <Name></Name>
       <ShortName></ShortName>
       <Kind></Kind>
       <Description></Description>
      <Vars></Vars>
      <Templates>       //список шаблонов
           <Template>
           <ID></ID>        //внутренний идентификатор
          <Name></Name> //имя на кириллице
          <ShortName></ShortName>   //имя на латинице
          <Description></Description>   //описание
          <PackageName></PackageName>
          <RootPackageName></RootPackageName>
          <Slots>       //список слотов
             <Slot>     //слот
               <Name></Name>
               <ShortName></ShortName>
               <Description></Description> 
               <Value></Value>          //значение слота
               <DataType></DataType>        //тип данных слота
               <Constraint></Constraint>    //ограничение на значение (=,>,<)
             </Slot>
          </Slots>
          </Template>
      </Templates>
      <Facts>       //список фактов
         <Fact> //факт
         <ID></ID>
         <Name></Name>
        <ShortName></ShortName>
       <Mode></Mode>
       <PackageName></PackageName>
       <RootPackageName></RootPackageName>
       <Slots>
          <Slot>
            <Name></Name>
            <ShortName></ShortName>
            <Description></Description> 
            <Value></Value>
            <DataType></DataType>
            <Constraint></Constraint>
          </Slot>
        </Slots>
        </Fact>
    </Facts>
    <GRules></GRules>
       <Rules>      //список правил
         <Rule>     //правило
         <ID></ID>
         <Name></Name>
         <ShortName></ShortName>
         <Description></Description>
         <Salience></Salience>      //важность правила
         <PackageName></PackageName>
         <RootPackageName></RootPackageName>
         <Conditions>       //список условий
           <Condition>      //условие
             <Name></Name>
             <Operator></Operator>  //оператор – and, or, not
             <Fact>
             <ID></ID>
             <Name></Name>
             <ShortName></ShortName>
              <Mode></Mode>
             <PackageName></PackageName>
             <RootPackageName></RootPackageName>
             <Slots>
               <Slot>
                 <Name></Name>
                 <ShortName></ShortName>
                 <Description></Description> 
                 <Value></Value>
                 <DataType></DataType>
                 <Constraint></Constraint>
               </Slot>
             </Slots>
             </Fact>
          </Condition>
       </Conditions>
      <Actions>     //список действий
      <Action>  //действие
          <Name></Name>
          <Operator></Operator> //оператор – add, rem
          <Fact>
            <ID></ID>
            <Name></Name>
            <ShortName></ShortName>
            <Mode></Mode>
           <PackageName></PackageName>
            <RootPackageName></RootPackageName>
           <Slots>
            <Slot>
            <Name></Name>
             <ShortName></ShortName>
              <Description></Description> 
              <Value></Value>
              <DataType></DataType>
              <Constraint></Constraint>
             </Slot>
          </Slots>
          </Fact>
        </Action>
     </Actions>
    </Rule> 
</Rules>
<Functions></Functions>
<Tasks></Tasks>
<TempPackageList></TempPackageList>
<FactPackageList></FactPackageList>
<RulePackageList></RulePackageList>
<GRulePackageList></GRulePackageList>
</KnowledgeBase>
</Structure>
```

Comment: Варианта по-моему два. 1)Десериализация - Сериализация. 2) xsl+xpath запрос. В зависимости от языка и задачи та или иная реализация. Ну как третий вариант - можно разобрать файл парсером xml, возможно так и само проще.

Comment: MDL (Rathional Rose) - разве не проприетарный формат?

Comment: Реверсинг формата MDL придется делать наверняка. Долго, дорого, сложно. Как итог - не нужно.